# How do I use CONCAT on SQL lite environment?

Tags: sqlite

How do you use CONCAT function on DEBEAVER environment. Thanks in advance

`CONCAT(CustomerID, "  ", CustomerName)`

Comment: The || operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings of its operands.

Comment: Still doesn't work in DEBEAVER sql lite. Here's my query. 
SELECT 
  concatenate(City ," - ",Country) country
FROM 
 customers c

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, The `||` operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings of its operands.

```sql
create table customer (
   customerId   int, 
   customerName text);

insert into customer
values
(101, 'Adam'),
(102, 'Eve');


select customerId || ' ' || customerName as customer_Id_and_Name
  from customer;
```

Result:

```
customer_Id_and_Name|
--------------------+
101 Adam            |
102 Eve             |
```

By the way, it's not limited in DBeaver. You can run the query in any SQLite query tools:

- sqlite3 (cli) - https://sqlite.org/cli.html
- SQLiteStudio - https://sqlitestudio.pl
- DB Browser for SQLite - https://sqlitebrowser.org